# Why don't work linkClicked, and works linkHovered PyQt4?

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtwebkit, qwebview

Here is some code. I created modal window, set easy html, and then I want to connect some method on click link. Signal "linkClicked" dont works , but link are loaded. And signal **linkHovered** works.  Where is mistake? And how to include some method to "linkClicked"?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtWebKit

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(1000, 500)
        self.menu_bar = self.menuBar()
        self.menuEngine()
    def menuEngine(self):
        self.podmenu2 = self.menu_bar.addMenu("Help")
        self.about = QtGui.QAction("About", self )
        self.about.setIconVisibleInMenu(True)
        self.podmenu2.addAction(self.about)
        self.about.triggered.connect(self.aboutView)
    def aboutView(self):
        def clicks(url):
            print("DDD")
            print(url)
        mod_window = QtGui.QWidget(self, QtCore.Qt.Window)
        mod_window.setWindowTitle("About")
        mod_window.resize(500, 332)
        horLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(mod_window)
        localHtmls = QtWebKit.QWebView()

        localHtmls.setHtml("""
            <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8"/>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div>
                    <br/>
                    Home page <a href="https://google.com">LINK</a>
                </div>
            </body>
            </html>
        """)
        horLayout.addWidget(localHtmls)

        localHtmls.linkClicked.connect(clicks)
        #localHtmls.page().linkHovered.connect(clicks)
        mod_window.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
     app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
     windows = MainWindow()
     windows.show()
     sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation for [linkClicked](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwebview.html#linkClicked):

> This signal is emitted whenever the user clicks on a link and the
>   page's linkDelegationPolicy property is set to delegate the link
>   handling for the specified url.

So try:

```
localHtmls.page().setLinkDelegationPolicy(QtWebKit.QWebPage.DelegateAllLinks)
```

But note that this completely bypasses the normal link-click handling, so you will have to implement that yourself (e.g. call `load(url)`).